# Problem with HttpWebRequest and post URL containing values

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to post to a URL that looks something like this:
"http://domain.com/api/?application_id=user&format=json&session_token=1824dsf1u312asd14"

I use the above as my request URL and write my data to the stream like this:

```
byte[] ByteQuery = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post_body);
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = ByteQuery.Length;
Stream QueryStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
QueryStream.Write(ByteQuery, 0, ByteQuery.Length);
QueryStream.Close();
```

That's all fine, the web page gets the post data no problem.  The problem is that it returns an error like this:

{"stat":"fail","diagnostics":"0 2.6 25.22","error":{"code":6,"message":"method (usermgmt.add) cannot change application_id to (user) in the same request when set to (null-app)."}}

So my question is, how do I handle sending post data to this page?  application_id has to be set in order to achieve my desired results.  I have also tried sending it through the RequestStream to no avail.

My post data as a string looks like this:

method=usermgmt.add&uid_to_add=5452007164&api_signature=&track=H40alhZWzp

The request I am trying to replicate:
http://pastebin.com/c38Cq3AR

Comment: Can you point us to the definition for the service?  It's telling you the request is set to `null-app` and that is a problem for this request?  Is there some way to set the app?

Comment: It seems to me the URI parameters aren't passed to the website. How are you creating your `httpWebRequest`?

Comment: @svick The parameters are being passed.  You can tell because the error contains the value of application_id that's set in the URI.

Comment: @NickLarsen I don't think there is a way to set the app.  Take a look at this PasteBin to see the request I am trying to replicate.
http://pastebin.com/c38Cq3AR

Comment: @FoxyGT: I don't see anything, I'd suggest sending their support team an email asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values.Add("method", "usermgmt.add");
            values.Add("uid_to_add", "5452007164");
            values.Add("api_signature", "");
            values.Add("track", "H40alhZWzp");

            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "a=b&c=d");
            wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "http://www.tagged.com/meetme.html");

            var returnBytes = wc.UploadValues("http://domain.com/api/?application_id=user&format=json&session_token=1824dsf1u312asd14", values);
            var returnJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(returnBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

do you still get the same responde?

EDIT: probably the cookies and/or referrer counts here? If so, I've added them to the code...

Comment: did you set the cookies? Are you supposed to be logged in to do this?

Comment: @Bruno The cookies are set and yes you are supposed to be logged in.

Comment: did you write any code to login first and get the responde cookies to use in the code above?

Comment: I'm logged in successfully.  The response I am getting would be different if I wasn't using my authentication cookies.

Comment: if you use the UploadString method from the WebClient do you get the same result?

Comment: Returns [ ] and doesn't achieve the desired results.